# Place elements from vector on histogram bins (R ggplot)

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I have a ggplot histogram, showing two histograms of a continuous variable, one for each level of a group.

Through use of ggplot_build, I now also have vectors where each element is the proportional count of one group (1) versus the other (0), per bin.

So for the following histogram built with

```
ggplot(data,aes(x=nonfordist)) + geom_histogram(aes(fill=presence),
position="identity",alpha=0.5,bins=30)+ coord_cartesian(xlim=c(NA,1750))
```

[image]

I have the following list, showing sequential proportions of group1/group0 per bin

```
list(0.398927744608261, 0.35358629130967, 0.275296034083078, 
    0.247361252979231, 0.260224274406332, 0.22107969151671, 0.252847380410023, 
    0.230055658627087, 0.212244897959184, 0.242105263157895, 
    0.235294117647059, 0.115384615384615, 0.2, 0.421052631578947, 
    0.4375, 0.230769230769231, 0.222222222222222, 0.5, 0, 0, 
    0, NaN, 1, 1, 0, 0, NaN, NaN, NaN, Inf)
```

What I want now is to plot the elements of this list on the corresponding bins, preferably above the bars showing the counts for group1.

I do not want to include the proportions for bins that fall outside of the histogram due to my xlim command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `stat_bin` with a text geom, using the same `breaks` as you do for your histogram. We don't have your actual data, so I've tried to approximate it here (see footnote for reproducible data). You haven't told us what your list of proportions is called, so I have named it `props` in this example.

```r
ggplot(data,aes(x=nonfordist)) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(fill = presence),
                 breaks = seq(-82.5, by = 165, length = 11),
                 position = "identity", alpha = 0.5, bins = 30) + 
  stat_bin(data = data[data$presence == 1, ], geom = "text",
             breaks = seq(-82.5, by = 165, length = 11),
           label = round(unlist(props)[1:10], 2), vjust = -0.5) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(NA, 1750))
```

[image]

---

**Approximation of data**

```r
data <- data.frame(
  nonfordist = rep(165 * c(0:10, 0:10),
                   c(24800, 20200, 16000, 6000, 2800, 1300, 700, 450, 100,
                     50, 30, 9950, 7400, 4500, 600, 300, 150, 80, 50, 30, 20,
                     10)),
  presence = factor(rep(c(0, 1), c(72430,  23090))))
```